# Observable casting from string to json

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, rxjs6

I am reading a JSON file from an S3 bucket. I am able to read the JSON file which is in the S3 bucket but when I am trying to cast the String Value into JSON and return it with an Observable. While subscribing I am getting the result as undefined. Could you please suggest how to get value as JSON when subscribing the observable

someexampleservice.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeEXampleService  {

_test2:any;

public getJSON(): Observable<any>  {
return Observable.create(observer=>{

   const params = {
  Bucket: 'some-bucket',
   Key: 'some.json'
    };

   let s3 = new AWS.S3();
  s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {
     if (err) {
     console.error(err); // an error occurred
   } else {

      console.log("S3 VAlue",data.Body); // Here I am getting the value as  
     String

    this._test2= data.Body.toString();
    console.log("S5 VAlue",this._test2);
    }
    });

   observer.next( this._test2);

  observer.complete();


    }) ;
   }
```

Basically, I am trying to get a JSON like below

```
public getJSON(): Observable<any> {
return this.http.get("./assets/some.json")//This same I am trying above 
with the s3 path
}
```

someTests.ts

```
 export class AuthorizationService  {

 constructor(private _auth: AuthorizationService,
          private _router: Router) { }

 ngOnInit(){


 this.getJSON().subscribe(data => {
 console.log("JsonValue",data); //This is coming as undefined
  });
  }
```

Comment: Check your browser console for any CORS Error. If you're not getting it, share your S3 JSON URL.

Comment: @SidAjmera I am able to read file from S3 and display it on the console. I am not getting any CORS error..I want to change the String value into JSON and return with  the Observable

Comment: You would actually get that data as JSON and not string. Probably what you're trying here is to append the data to your log by placing a `+` instead of `,` in the call to your `console.log`

Comment: I tried what you suggested still getting as undefined.I am using data.Body.toString() this will give a string as value

Comment: Can you replicate this on a sample [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular)?

Comment: I am getting Body: Uint8Array(131)
[0 … 99]
[100 … 130]... If I remove toString().How do I get the body as JSON

Comment: You may need to use the text-encoding library polyfill to use TextDecoder:
https://github.com/inexorabletash/text-encoding

Comment: By using JSON.parse(data.Body). I am able to get the JSON value in Observable but while subscribing still it is coming as undefined

Comment: Please edit your snippets - make them line up and remove misleading comments. You cant get both -  `// an error occurred` and `// Here I am getting the value as  ` in `if/else` if you complete Observable